# Multiple columns return in CASE Statement SQL

Tags: sql, case

I have two tables and based on the sum of a field in **TABLE1** I have to return different datasets from TABLE2:

I am trying to achieve this through a Case statement but getting an error saying ***subselect must have only one field.***

Is there a better way to do this? simply when the sum of a column in table1 is 0 do not select anything from table2

TABLE1:
[image]

TABLE2:
[image]

MY SQL:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
   WHEN SUM(transaction_unit_failed) > 0 
   THEN (
         SELECT sale_event_nr, business_unit, transaction_nr, transaction_unit_failed_number
        FROM TABLE2
        )
   WHEN SUM(transaction_unit_failed) = 0 
   THEN (
         SELECT sale_event_nr, business_unit, transaction_nr, transaction_unit_failed_number
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE 1 = 2
 
        )
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use data from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table2
where exists (
    select 1
    from table1
    having sum(transaction_unit_failed) > 0
);
```

Similarly:

```
select * from table2
where (
    select sum(transaction_unit_failed)
    from table1
) > 0;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3f68d250bc9a3235767b86626092799e

You could certainly write it as a join if there were a compelling reason. It would eliminate the convenience of nicely using `*` to return only the columns from the one table.

```
select *
from table2 inner join (
    select sum(transaction_unit_failed) as stuf
    from table1
) on stuf > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT sale_event_nr, business_unit, transaction_nr, transaction_unit_failed_number
   FROM TABLE2
  WHERE (SELECT SUM(transaction_unit_failed) > 0 
                     FROM TABLE1)
```